# Django ManyToMany with through model implementation

Tags: python, django, django-models

So let's say I have these models in my Django app:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, 
        through='RecipeIngredient')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ingredient.name
```

Now I want to access a recipe's ingredients (really RecipeIngredients). Via the Django shell:

```
>>> r = Recipe.objects.get(id=1)
>>> ingredients = RecipeIngredients.objects.filter(recipe=r)
```

This seems counter-intuitive and clunky to me. Ideally I'd like to be able to have a Recipe object and get RecipeIngredients from it directly.

Is there a more elegant implementation of my models? Is there any way to improve my existing model implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `related_name`, just as you would with a normal `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`:

```
class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name='ingredient_quantities')
```

And then:

```
>>> r = Recipe.objects.get(id=1)
>>> ingredients = r.ingredient_quantities.all()
```

Comment: I didn't even realize I could've accessed `recipeingredients_set` X( Seems obvious now... Thanks!